# Can't understand how to do it with javascript and jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry guys for asking that dumb question but I have problem with that thing. 
Have such script, it should return true or false, but after drawing that html pop-up window and getting response from that methods.

```
           $("#pageInfo a.btnDel").click(function () {

                    $("#cmsSmallPopUpWindowMessage").html("<h2>Do you really want to delete this page?</h2><center><div style='width:130px'><ul class='bactions'><li><a id='cmsSmallPopUpWindowBYes' href='javascript:void(0)'><span><span>Yes</span></span></a></li><li><a id='cmsSmallPopUpWindowBNo' href='javascript:void(0)'><span><span>No</span></span></a></li></ul><div class='archor'></div></div></center>");
                    $.blockUI({ message: $("#cmsSmallPopUpWindow"), css: { width: "530px", border: "0px", backgroundColor: "transparent"} });
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $.unblockUI();
                    }, 6000);


                    $("#cmsSmallPopUpWindowBNo").click(function () {
                        $.unblockUI();
                        return false;
                    });


                    $("#cmsSmallPopUpWindowBYes").click(function () {
                        $.unblockUI();
                        location.reload();
                        return onDelete($(this).attr('href'));
                    });
                    return true; // this should change for "false" or "true" but after click on "yes" or "no" 


                });
```

Comment: What you're looking for is `.confirm()`. Take a look at this plugin: http://nadiana.com/jquery-confirm-plugin

Comment: Don't generate inline HTML inside js code, use templating better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [jQueryUI modal-confiramtion dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation). It just fits your needs, blocks the UI (modal), has a nice layout and works assync (not freezing the script).